# Magento Custom Options Pricing Fix from Database

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9, price

So it's a bit of a long story, but I've got a client who runs a Magento Ecomerce site on CE 1.9.0.1 and she was under the impression that she knew how to use custom options for products...

She's gone ahead and set her team on creating thousands of products using custom options for bulk buys etc and set prices for each of these. Unfortunately however she was under the impression the pricing in custom options was the new price, not an additional price and as such she's done it like so.

```
ProductA = PriceA
Option1 = PriceB
Option2 = PriceC
```

As such when you select ProductA with Option1 you get PriceA + PriceB.

So somehow I need to be able to go through all these products and from each product with custom options remove PriceA from PriceB,C,D etc.

To be specific, I was hoping somebody could point me in the direction of a way to edit the products from the database to adjust the pricing and make it so that

```
ProductA = PriceA
Option1 = PriceA
Option2 = PriceB
```

by removing the original product price from any Custom Option prices

Hope this makes some sense and in turn gives others a chance to learn a little bit more about the magento database structure...

Thanks

---

In response to Sagi,

I'd like to take the existing products (please see http://leedshydroponics.com/biobizz-light-mix-50l.html as an example) and make the 20L option +£0.00 and the 50L option +£4.00 (£10.95 - £6.95)

Thanks

---

Here we go again @Sagi

So in the table **catalog_product_option** I have a link between **option_id** and **product_id**

This links my custom options to the products they're related to...

I then have a table called **catalog_product_option_type_price** which has two columns which I am interested in, **option_id** and **price**

Then in a table called **catalog_product_index_price** i have **entity_id** and **price**

I then have to link **entity_id** to **product_id** which is where I get a little lost

Comment: Please add a specific question. What do you want?

Comment: Sorry I thought this explained it... "somehow I need to be able to go through all these products and from each product with custom options remove PriceA from PriceB,C,D etc" ill edit my question to be a little more specific

Comment: Please provide input and expected output.. that way we will know how to help you.

Comment: Hey @sagi please see my edit above... thanks

Comment: @KittMedia likewise... Thank you in anticipation

Comment: I meant tables input and output, show us the table structure and columns and then what you expect the output to be..

Comment: @Sagi... unfortunatly thats part of my issue, I am not sure where this data lies in the magento table structure :/

Comment: I've added a litle more details. Does this help?